# Is there any way to make new browser tabs on open the same workspace as the opening program?

Tags: unity, workspace-switcher

Quite a major usability issue here, as I'm running 24 workspaces and constantly have to find where the IRC link I just opened went, so willing to put lots of effort to get it fixed.

Edit: locking each program to a certain workspace is not the solution here as I have several different purpose chromium windows open.  One for music, one for work communications, one for work references, one for random browsing etc.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Will that really solve this? In this question, presumably the browser may already be open, and it's not the same application as the program that tried to open the new tab.

Comment: 24 workspaces!!! That's crazy. And as you found out, finding which workspace contains what you're looking for is impossible! You can look at `Compiz Config Manager` and it has a `Place Windows` plugin that will put specific apps into specific workspaces... amongst other things.

Comment: @EliahKagan probably not *literally* what OP asked for, since it locks the application (in this case the browser) to a specific workspace, not necessarily the one that has the launching window. It wil definitely end the search though. I will remove the close vote though if OP mentions it is not what he is looking for.

Comment: Retracted my vote! @EliahKagan

Comment: I usually use 8-14 but sometimes run up to 20ish...  16gb ram so no issue w memory...  Really hard to live w less afrer getting used to it.  Cant stand having more than one purpose and one  window on one workspace

Comment: @Lynob having many workspaces (viewports) is not really a burden to your system. I have automatically viewports added when I run out of them. 24 of them happens quite regularly on my elderly system without a single issue.

Comment: I could give you my answer to this problem, but it isn't what you want and you wouldn't like it. So instead I'll just comment that it's really easy to find any application I'm running on a single workspace. Alt-TAB is quite useful.